# How to find last time DHCP reservation was active?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dhcp

Within the DHCP snap-in, I have many DHCP reserverations in my list of address leases. Some of these reservations I suspect are ancient and are not being used any more. Under Address Leases, some of the leases are marked as `Reservation (inactive)` in the Lease Expiration column. Is there a way to see the last time that an inactive lease was indeed active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search for the MAC address in the plain text log files at this path:

`%system32%\dhcp\DhcpSrvLog.*`

...you will be able to see each time that MAC address checked in with the server within the last 7 days.  Note that I tried this on a Server 2000 machine -- the path may be slightly different in a 2003 environment.

To find the MAC address, you can look it up in the DHCP reservation or run  `ipconfig /all`  on the computer with the reservation.